# Calculate the gradient of a concentration from concentration and space values

Tags: r

it seems very simple but I am having a little problem here. I have concentration and location(x) data. I want to find the gradient(dc/dx) from the data set.

The data set can be found on https://www.dropbox.com/s/xgo3cx8i3xz27w3/concentration.csv

A sample data is given here:

```
       x      conc
1    0.0 1.0000000
2    0.5 1.0000000
3    1.0 1.0000000
4    1.5 1.0000000
5    2.0 1.0000000
6    2.5 1.0000000
7    3.0 1.0000000
8    3.5 1.0000000
9    4.0 1.0000000
10   4.5 1.0000000
11   5.0 1.0000000
12   5.5 1.0000000
13   6.0 1.0000000
14   6.5 1.0000000
15   7.0 1.0000000
16   7.5 1.0000000
17   8.0 1.0000000
18   8.5 1.0000000
19   9.0 1.0000000
20   9.5 1.0000000
21  10.0 1.0000000
22  10.5 1.0000000
23  11.0 1.0000000
24  11.5 1.0000000
25  12.0 1.0000000
26  12.5 1.0000000
27  13.0 1.0000000
28  13.5 1.0000000
29  14.0 1.0000000
30  14.5 1.0000000
31  15.0 1.0000000
32  15.5 1.0000000
33  16.0 1.0000000
34  16.5 1.0000000
35  17.0 1.0000000
36  17.5 1.0000000
37  18.0 1.0000000
38  18.5 0.9999999
39  19.0 0.9999999
40  19.5 0.9999999
41  20.0 0.9999999
42  20.5 0.9999999
43  21.0 0.9999999
44  21.5 0.9999999
45  22.0 0.9999999
46  22.5 0.9999999
47  23.0 0.9999998
48  23.5 0.9999998
49  24.0 0.9999998
50  24.5 0.9999998
51  25.0 0.9999998
52  25.5 0.9999997
53  26.0 0.9999997
54  26.5 0.9999997
55  27.0 0.9999996
56  27.5 0.9999996
57  28.0 0.9999995
58  28.5 0.9999995
59  29.0 0.9999994
60  29.5 0.9999994
61  30.0 0.9999993
62  30.5 0.9999992
63  31.0 0.9999991
64  31.5 0.9999990
65  32.0 0.9999989
66  32.5 0.9999988
67  33.0 0.9999987
68  33.5 0.9999986
69  34.0 0.9999984
70  34.5 0.9999982
71  35.0 0.9999981
72  35.5 0.9999979
73  36.0 0.9999976
74  36.5 0.9999974
75  37.0 0.9999971
76  37.5 0.9999969
77  38.0 0.9999965
78  38.5 0.9999962
79  39.0 0.9999958
80  39.5 0.9999954
81  40.0 0.9999950
82  40.5 0.9999945
83  41.0 0.9999940
84  41.5 0.9999934
85  42.0 0.9999928
86  42.5 0.9999921
87  43.0 0.9999913
88  43.5 0.9999905
89  44.0 0.9999896
90  44.5 0.9999887
91  45.0 0.9999876
92  45.5 0.9999865
93  46.0 0.9999853
94  46.5 0.9999839
95  47.0 0.9999825
96  47.5 0.9999809
97  48.0 0.9999792
98  48.5 0.9999773
99  49.0 0.9999754
100 49.5 0.9999732
```

The gradient can be found as the following formula

dc/dx = (c2-c1)/(x2-x1)

So, the first value doesn't have the gradient and I need to find the gradient for rest of the points using the above formula.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that's a `data.frame`, called `df`

```
df$gradient <- c(NA, diff(df$c)/diff(df$x))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

With center finite differences 
where x is the vector (concentration)
res, distance between points (resolution, in your case 0.5)
dx the gradient

The method uses this formula for the values among the extremes

dx(n) = (x(n+1)-x(n-1))/(res(n+1) - res(n-1))

and the extremes are calculated using the forward approach

dx(n) = (x(n+1)-x(n))/(res(x+1)-res(x)) 
dx(m) = (x(m) - x(m-1))/res(m) - res(m-1))

```
center_finite_diff <- function(x, res) {
    dx <- vector(mode="numeric",length=length(x))
    m <- end(x)
    dx[1] <- diff(x[1:2])/res
    dx[m[1]] <- diff(x[(m[1]-1):m[1]])/res
    dx[2:(m[1]-1)] <- diff(x, 2)/(2*res)
    return(dx)
}
```